# Editing component config in Joomla

Tags: joomla

So on a component I am editing, I see a "template" for a list it shows on a component page of it's own.

I found the files for each template:

[image: Component option]

I copied the "default" template and made a new name for my own edits

But I can't figure out how it's gonna be added on that ^ list

```
if($Config['config_view_template'] == 1) {

    $view->setLayout('rounded');

}elseif($Config['config_view_template'] == 2) {

    $view->setLayout('basic');

}


$Params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_xxxxxx');

$ParamsArray = $pcParams->toArray();

foreach($ParamsArray['params'] as $name => $value){

  $Config[(string)$name] = (string)$value;

}
```

My question is, how to add another choice to a selection option on Joomla components? (see image)

Alternate question: How does a component add options?

I tried looking on the this component's directory, but I found nothing, it seems like it just have that `JComponentHelper::getParams('com_xxxxxx')` that already knows the options set by the time it is called? Upon installation, how does it register it's options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure about modern Joomla versions, but have had to add params to components in the past in Joomla 1.5 (which is one of the most common versions out there) so hopefully this will help.

Most components have a main component in the `components` directory as well as an administrator component connected to them in the `administrator` directory under `administrator/components/`.

Using your `com_xxxxxx` as an example—& assuming your document root is `/var/www/`—it would be here:

```
/var/www/administrator/components/com_xxxxxx/config.xml
```

The `config.xml` is the key. And it will contain items like this for a `text` item:

```
<param type="text" name="something_cool" size="36" label="Cool Thing:" description="A very cool thing." />
```

And then if you wanted a select list:

```
<param name="cool_list" type="list" default="1" label="Select Cool Options" description="Here are some cool options to select.">
    <option value="0">Awesome</option>
    <option value="1">Amazing</option>
    <option value="2">Super Amazing</option>
</param>
```

And the over structure of that `config.xml` with those items would be like this:

```
<root>
  <params>

    <param type="text" name="something_cool" size="36" label="Cool Thing:" description="A very cool thing." />

    <param name="cool_list" type="list" default="1" label="Select Cool Options" description="Here are some cool options to select.">
        <option value="0">Awesome</option>
        <option value="1">Amazing</option>
        <option value="2">Super Amazing</option>
    </param>

  </params>
</root>
```

Then, if you want to set default values for any of that, you would go into `manifest.xml` and somewhere near the bottom—at least when I did this—will be a list of param defaults you can set like this:

```
<params>
    <param name="something_cool" default="" />
</params>
```

I have only used the defaults in `manifest.xml` for `text` entries since it seems that a default can be set for `list` values without that, but I would experiment.

Comment: thanks for the help! I found config.xml containing a bit different format ( config > fields > fieldset > field instead of root params > param ) but exactly the same attributes ( field and param) Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: That's because he's looking at 1.5. some of the vocabulary changed and metadata.xml are not used as much, though still highly useful.